# how to print out the results with the arithmetic operations?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I have made a class

```
class CompositeNumber : public Number
```

And I have included the information that needs to be stored which are

```
Number* first;
Number* second;
```

Now I have been told "mainly the other numbers from which it was composed (so it can be split again), the operation that was used (+, -, *, /) for printing, and possibly its value (for convenience, so you don't have to re-compute it all the time)" but I have no clue how to do that at all.

If this is still not understandable then for example:

1. a GivenNumber object representing the number 3
2. another GivenNumber object representing the number 4
3. a CompositeNumber object, which has pointers to the first two objects, a variable representing the operator '+', and a total value of 7.
   Then The printMe method in the third object should then print "7 = (3+4)" using the available data (it will also have to recursively call the printMe method in the two GivenNumber objects)

Here is the whole code that I have done so far for the CompositeNumber class

```
class CompositeNumber : public Number {
Number* first;
Number* second;

int getValue;


bool isSpittable() {
    return true;
}

public: void printMe() {

/*cout << "1 . Add = +" << endl;
cout << "2 . Subtract = -" << endl;
cout << "3 . Multiply = *" << endl;
cout << "4 . Divide = /" << endl;
*/

cout << getValue;
}
};
```

Comment: Having trouble understanding exactly what you are asking. This could be as simple as storing the operator used as an extra `char` member variable and setting this value in the constructor.

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: This question needs more details to clarify the problem.

Comment: okay sorry for this, give me a few minutes to question this properly

Comment: I have given an example, hopefully this helps